# Swift In Autolayout TextView NSLayoutConstraint Not change , Height change of Textview Dynamic

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I have Zero knowledge of Auto-layout , In view i have one UITextView with height of 115 , width of 320, if i have some images in array then i have textview height set 50 to 60 and show image below of textView , I am Trying set to **NSLayoutConstraint** but I cant able to change height of textview. 
Please give me solution, Here is my code

First I Try this

```
@IBOutlet var txt_description: UITextView!
     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: txt_description, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view_of_segment, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant:10))
    }
```

Second is

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: txt_description, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: txt_title, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 24),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: txt_description, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: txt_title, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: txt_description, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: txt_title, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: txt_description, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:4)
            ])


}
```

Third I Try this

```
@IBOutlet var EqualHeight_txt_des: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var txt_description: UITextView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
 let leftiPadWidth:CGFloat = 50
        txt_description.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
       EqualHeight_txt_des.constant = leftiPadWidth
    }
```

Please give me solution 
I can't able change textview height 
please share your valuable knowledge